# send data to server using https using CURL

Tags: c, curl, https

can any one tell me the process for sending data to https.
   what are the prerequisite to send data to https server.
   With example is highly appreciable.

Comment: You can find the answer in [this](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) page

Comment: please add some code , what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [curl over https](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/).